# Get Portal Version using JavaScript or Liquid

Tags: dynamics-crm-portals

Is there a way of retrieving the current Portal Version using JavaScript and/or Liquid?

I know I can visit `/_services/about` to view the current Version Number, but is there a way of getting this value on a standard `Web Page` or `Web Template`?

We're currently having problems with some code written for different versions of the portal and we'd like to be able to detect which version we're using programmatically.

[image: Services/About]

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the Portal html code that introduces a `Microsoft.Dynamic365` object that appears to have the properties that I was looking for.

[image: Portal Source]

I'm still trying to find where these are introduced as I'm not sure if these are the result of some liquid or via some other method